# Why is double-checked locking not used properly in the implementation of System.console() in the openJDK?

Tags: java, singleton, double-checked-locking, system-console

In the *openJDK* source code, the [`System.console()`](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/lang/System.java) was implemented as such:

```
 private static volatile Console cons = null;
/**
 * Returns the unique {@link java.io.Console Console} object associated
 * with the current Java virtual machine, if any.
 *
 * @return  The system console, if any, otherwise <tt>null</tt>.
 *
 * @since   1.6
 */
 public static Console console() {
     if (cons == null) {
         synchronized (System.class) {
             cons = sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOAccess().console();
         }
     }
     return cons;
 }
```

IMO, this implementation is lack of the *double-checked locking*, say the `null` *test* inside the `synchronized` block is absent. In this case **assuming 2 threads, thread I gets into the `synchronized` *monitor* and, in the same time thread II coincidentally gets blocked on the same `synchronized` *monitor*, as a result, thread II would also get chance to call the `cons = sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOAccess().console();` to initialized the Console object again**

**Question**: Why isn't the *double-checked locking* used properly in this case? Is this really a flaw of the *openJDK*?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because the `Console` object returned by `sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOAccess().console()` is [already initialised](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/ddcbc20e8c6a/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/Console.java#l554) as a static-block singleton anyway. The worst that could happen is that `cons` gets set to the same thing again.

Is it ideal? Probably not. Is it intentional? Maybe. Will it cause side effects? I don't think so.